# Creating a function that uses dplyr where arguments are passed into filter

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have done an analysis of my dataset but in long-form and would like to write a function to automate a part which I had to write multiple times over.

```
#Null_proband outputs for disease tables
null.proband <- dbdata %>%
  filter(Proband == TRUE & Fam.state.mainmut.MutGroup == "Null") %>%
  group_by(ICD_Grouping) %>%
  summarise(n_distinct(PID),
            n_distinct(Fam.state.mainmut.FID),
            n(),
            median(AgeOfOnset))

#Column names for null_proband
colnames(null.proband) = c("ICD_Grouping", "proband_uniq(PID)", "proband_uniq(FID)", "proband_freq(PID)","proband_median(ageofonset)")
```

I repeat this multiple times for different filtering sets and I was wondering if I can have a base function with a selection of if clauses

`f1 <- function(x, pop = c("proband", "nonproband", "carrier", "unknown", "all), mut = ("null", "mis", "unk", "all"))`

Is how I would want the set up for the function then a base dplyr process

```
{ pop.mut <- dbdata %>%
filter(defined by arguments) %>%
group_by(ICD_Grouping) %>%
summarise(pop_uniqPID = n_distinct(PID),
          pop_uniqFID = n_distinct(FID),
          pop_freqPID = n(),
          pop_medianAgeOfOnset = median(AgeOfOnset))
}
```

And then if clauses describing what the filter should depending on the argument e.g.

```
if (pop = "proband" & mut = "null") { filter(Proband == TRUE & Fam.state.mainmut.Mutgroup == "Null") }
```

and write for loops for all the combinations or can I write for loops for half the filter with arguments or just filter once for one argument then filter a second time for the second argument?